# Random black boxes

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, graphics

These black boxes showed up after restarting my computer and they blink on and off. Not sure where they came from and they occur before I login to my computer. I am running Ubuntu 12.10 and I have a nVidia graphic card and had to disable the default graphic system that ships with Ubuntu.

If you need more information let me know.

Sorry that I used a picture of my screen, the boxes didn't show up on a screenshot.

[image: The black boxes]

Comment: Laptop or desktop? Did you reboot the computer or power it off then back on? Are the boxes blinking at a regular rate (about how much)? Do they move?

Comment: Desktop (3 Monitors; DVI, HDMI, DisplayPort). I have rebooted my computer a couple times.
They blink rapidly or stay solid.
They will occasionally change monitor but haven't found what causes that.

Comment: Went into my nVidia control panel and ran a reset, boxes disappeared after a restart.

Comment: Close voters: This question has been answered (just not accepted). **There is no need to close this**. Please upvote the answer.

Answer (score 4):

After reseting my nVidia settings to factory defaults and restarting my computer the boxes disappeared. Not sure what caused this as I hadn't changed my nVidia settings.

Answer (score 0):

This same thing happened to me occasionally in 12.10, and it happened consistently in 13.04. I'm using the proprietary nvidia driver (I have the 8400GS) and the problem persisted through trying different versions of the driver.

After looking around I found that it was the vesafb module that was causing the issue (you'll probably notice some complaints from dmesg about vesafb). After I uncommented 'blacklist vesafb' in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf the problem went away.

The only problem now is I have lost my ttys, and I'm still trying to figure out how to get them back.